# Invalid argument '$0' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting from backend as `$0`, i want to display it as `$0.00` in my UI.

```
<span [innerHTML]="session.balance | currency :'USD': true:'1.2-2'"></span>
```

Why is it failing when my `backend` gives me the balance as `$0` and does not fail when it gives me just a `number 0`. This was working fine in `Angular 1` while using the `currency` filter.

Removing the `currency` filter also removed the `two decimal places` which i used to get. I am not sure whether i should go with `number : '1.2-2'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The currency pipe only accepts numbers as valid input.

If your backend is providing you a `$` symbol, remove it using the [`slice`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/SlicePipe-pipe.html) pipe before you pass it to the `currency` pipe

`{{ session.balance | slice : '1' |  currency : 'USD' : true : '1.2-2' }}`